# How to expand and contract the current selection in Edit mode?

Tags: selection-tools

I watched a video of somebody selecting more vertices/edges/faces using the <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> signs in edit mode. He would select one face then using the <kbd>></kbd> sign it would select more connected faces.

The problem is I'm on a Mac and those two keys are under the <kbd>**,**</kbd> and <kbd>**.**</kbd> that will also no work using the the shift key.
Is there another shortcut to do this?

Comment: I've tried those, and I can't get it to work. What exactly does it do in the video? Extend the selection in a specific direction? The closest thing I know of is `Ctrl` `Numpad +` and `Ctrl` `Numpad -`, which expands and contracts the selection in all directions.

Comment: @SixthOfFour Yes it does exactly what the ctrl + and - do. Thanks! That answered my question.

Comment: That's good. I added it as an answer. I also edited the title of your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The key combinations to expand and contract the selection are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> (to expand) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad -</kbd> (to contract). Like this:
[image]

*Note: I'm not using an English keyboard, and the <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> may work on an English keyboard. I honestly don't know*

Comment: `<` and `>` do nothing for me, and searching for shortcuts using these keys reveals no results. Most likely the user in the tutorial was using the maya keymap, where `shift` `,` and `shift` `.` are used to do this.

Comment: How do you do this without a numpad?

Comment: Yeah. I'd also love to know how to do this without a numpad. Blender has a frustrating reliance on numpad shortcuts. Neither my pc keyboard, nor my mac keyboard have a numpad.